# Insert Ignore in MySql when there's primary key that auto increments

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I use insert ignore in Mysql when there's a column that's `primary key`, and that `auto increments`.

I have `primary keys` on `id` (primary key auto increment), and `userId` and `elmCol` are primary keys with no auto increment.

So:

```
id | userId | elmCol
--------------------
 1 | 1     | 1 //Allow
 2 | 1     | 2 //Allow
 3 | 1     | 3 //Allow
 4 | 1     | 1 //Not allowed if inserted again. I've put it in here just for example
 5 | 2     | 1 //Allow
 6 | 2     | 2 //Allow
 7 | 2     | 3 //Allow
 8 | 2     | 1 //Not allowed if inserted again. I've put it in here just for example
```

I'm using MySql and MyIsam type tables. Can I do something like this and use `insert ignore`?

Comment: There can only be one primary key in a table, although it can be a combination of fields, so you need to clarify what your set-up is. And what do you mean by "insert ignore"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for `INSERT IGNORE` to work in your case you need to create a UNIQUE index on `(userId, elmCol)`.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT u_userId_elmCol 
    UNIQUE (userID, elmCol);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b080d/1)** demo.

Comment: Thanks... Working perfectly. For now :)